Curious about the math portion of subjects
I am a long time civil engineer. But I am interested in learning electrical electronics engineering and lately have been teaching myself about analog electronics, signals, digital electronics... One question. Do I need to be concerned about the seemingly complex set of math equations I see in many places? For example I was studying an undergraduate level analog electronics text, given to students at a university for a semester. It talks about Fourier series when representing signals as sum of multiple signals. Now, I perfectly understand the idea, but I don't quite understand the math behind it, I mean the equations itself. Do I need to also grasp the math portion fully in order to be able to proceed further in my learning - not just this subject but in general?

A rough idea will probably do. It's not like you need to prove theorems or anything. But you should be solid on algebra and trig, that's the level where the work is IRL. You should also have at least the rough outlines of calculus (outside of school, no need to actually work out integrals or anything), and similarly the rough outlines of a first course in differential equations, and some related subjects for frequency domain subjects (for some EE topics, Fourier Transform and its relative, Laplace Transform, which happens to transform LTI differential equations into high school algebra).

The answer has to do with whether or not you want to be able to solve problems in the field. If you don't, then you do not have to worry about mastery of the math because you'll never be using it. If your intent is instead to solve homework problems, then mastery of the math is essential.

Yes and no. Depends heavily on what you do with your electronics. Both Laplace and Fourier are useful, both conceptually and on a symbolical level.
Fourier being relatively simple so have found myself accidentally do a discrete fourier while trying to solve a problem. Also I have seen others do it aswell, for example a graphic designer stumbled on it while trying to visualize temperatures.
In reality linear algebra, trig, calculus is often enough for most work. But depends heavily and guides what you end up doing. If you do heavy signal processing or computation then I suggest you brush on it. Fourier is even useful for programmers as many algorithms are computationally faster in frequency domains.
Anyway, you will never recognize the need for something you do not know. Therefore not need. Possibly very expensive for your employer.
PS: I would also like to leave a warning. Most of the future work is work that hasn't been done yet. Therefore reflecting on what is currently needed is not super useful. Simply you need to be a bit over educated to get to the state of the art. Now if all you want to do is replace an existing job then fine, but it might not be a good career goal.
